# Text field default background color

Tags: html, css, background, textarea

As you know all browsers have default styles for text fields which vary. But is there any browser in which the text filed, e.g. `textarea`, background color isn't white?

Comment: Text browser for starters!

Comment: Why do you ask? If you want it to be specifically white, why don’t you just set it to white?

Comment: @Jukka K. Korpela: If all browsers do it by default, why should I add this redundant style?

Comment: For example because a user style sheet may set it.

Comment: How can a user style sheet modify my page document which is hosted on my domain?

Comment: Every browser uses a stylesheet for its default styles. A userstylesheet overwrites that one. CSS is being handled by your users browsers, not by your servers. They merely pass on the sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you searching for browser that can render different color. You can do it by your own for any browser by css

```
input[type=text]{
    background:#fff; /*Any color You wanted*/
  }
textarea{
    background:#fff; /*Any color You wanted*/
  }
```

Comment: It's white by default in my browsers , but I wonder if it's reliable to just leave it as is and be sure other browsers render it white.

Comment: I think all the browser render it white.

Answer (score -1):

Check this on [js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/C5WxK/).

```
input[type="text"], textarea {  
  background-color : red;   
}
```

Hope you need this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I already know how to customize a text field background color.

Comment: Not an answer at all.